Find the Laurent Series of $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-6)(z+4)}$
Can someone help me find the Laurent Series centered at $z=6$ for $f(z) = \frac{1}{(z-6)(z+4)}?$ I was going to start by rewriting this as $f(w) = \frac{1}{w(w+10)}$ so that I can find the Laurent Series centered at $w=0$ and then let $w=z-6$ in the end. However, I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Note that $\dfrac1{(z-6)(z+4)}=\dfrac1{10}\left(\dfrac1{z-6}-\dfrac1{z+4}\right)$

Hints:
$\dfrac1{(z-6)(z+4)}=\dfrac1{10}\left(\dfrac1{z-6}-\dfrac1{z+4}\right)$
$\dfrac1{z+4}=\dfrac1{10+z-6}=\dfrac1{10}\dfrac1{1+\dfrac{z-6}{10}}$
$\dfrac1{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+\cdots$

If you want to center your series at 6.
$z = w+6$
$f(w+6) = \frac {1}{w(w+10)}$
Remember that:
$\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac {1}{1-x}$
We want to find a factor that is in the form of the expression on the right.
$(\frac {1}{10w})(\frac {1}{1+\frac {w}{10}})$
And use $(-\frac {w}{10})$ in the power series above
$(\frac {1}{10w})\sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} (-\frac {w}{10})^n$
$f(w+6) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac {w^{n-1}}{10^{n+1}}$
$w = z-6$
$f(z) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac {(z-6)^{n-1}}{10^{n+1}}$
Or you can use partial fractions as the other answer shows.
